# Oracle - Bulk multiple row Calculation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a similar requirement as below

Table Name : Salary_detail(has at least 10,00,000 records)

columns

> salary - Number
>
> hike   - Number
>
> net_salary --> cal_netsal(salary,hike)

(cal_netsal is a function to calculate net_sal)

> total_sal ---> total_sal(salary,hike)

total_sal is a function

> previous_sal --> previous_sal(salary,hike)

previous_sal is a function.

I need to calculate net_salary,total_sal and previous_sal columns

> 1.I need to calculate all three columns in a single row
>
> 2.insert back to the corresponding columns in that table.
>   what would be the best way to achieve this?

Kindly help

Comment: What I understand is, Salary and hike Column is already populated in a table and you need to update the other 3 column ,is it correct?

Comment: Yes!!! its already there , we need to populate the rest,
BTW its a part of performance improvement :(

Comment: 'UPDATE salary_details
   SET net_salary = cal_netsal (salary, hike),
       total_sal = total_sal (salary, hike),
       previous_sal = previous_sal (salary, hike)
 WHERE 1 = 1 '

Comment: 'select salary,hike,cal_netsal(salary,hike) as net_salary,total_sal(salary,hike) as total_sal,previous_sal(salary,hike) as previous_sal
from salary_details'

Comment: should we use some bulk collect etc. for any performance improvement ? or is this the best way to achieve this . Kindly help

Comment: This is the best way to handle existing records ,because bulk collect will be written in PLSQL block and at the end PLSQL engine in turn calls the sql engine to execute the update query ,so why not directly writing the query in sql and avoid context switching  and for new records ,please find the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily update the existing column by using the functions already created,The below update will take care of the existing records in the table.

```
UPDATE salary_details 
  SET net_salary = cal_netsal (salary, hike)
     , total_sal = total_sal (salary, hike)
     , previous_sal = previous_sal (salary, hike) WHERE 1 = 1
```

If new records are inserted or updated in the table,you can create a before insert trigger that will update the existing columns and no need to do it manually each time later on after the trigger is created.Trigger will take care of the DML operation happening on the table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  sal_biu_trg
              BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON salary_details
                 FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        :NEW.net_salary = cal_netsal (:NEW.salary,:NEW.hike);
        :NEW.total_sal = total_sal (:NEW.salary,:NEW.hike);
        :NEW.previous_sal = previous_sal (:NEW.salary,:NEW.hike);
     END IF;  
   EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
       dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);  
   END;
/
```

Comment: Upvoted, except `WHEN OTHERS THEN dbms_output...` is anathema.  But the question isn't about exception handling, so I'll just get over it... :)

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: Even i also dislikes dbms_output in the exception handling ,Its just for showing the structure of trigger nothing else :) and it depends on individual how to handle exception ,log it  , raise it etc etc

Comment: Thank you Gaurav :)